# When does encodeWithCoder get called?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, nscoder

This will save an array (I think).

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:myArray forKey:@"myArray"];
}
```

Do I have to directly call this method when I want to save an array or do I have to do something else?

Comment: Don't forget to call super:

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [super encodeWithCoder:coder];

    [encoder encodeObject:myArray forKey:@"myArray"];
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don’t call this method directly. It’s called by a `NSCoder` subclass if it needs to serialize that object. If you want to encode an object graph use the class methods `archivedDataWithRootObject:` or `archiveRootObject:toFile:` of `NSKeyedArchiver`. This in turn will call the `encodeWithCoder:` method of your objects. Also note that every object in your array has to implement the `NSCoding` protocol.

Comment: I am using RMMapper library to set value in UserDefaults. The library uses     NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:obj]; to encode the object but still this method is not called. I have been stuck on this issue for long. Can you help me with this?