# Storing custom OrderedDictionary to NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I need to save the [OrderedDictionary](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html) to NSUserDefaults.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults) and in many other posts how to do it:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder{
     if (self != nil){
         dictionary = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"dictionary"];
         array = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"array"];
     }
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{
    [encoder encodeObject: dictionary forKey:@"dictionary"];
    [encoder encodeObject: array forKey:@"array"];
}
```

I then call it like this:

```
 OrderedDictionary *od = [OrderedDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[businessInfo objectForKey:@"allowedStates"]];
    NSData *archivedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:od];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:archivedObject forKey:@"allowedStates"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

and unarchive it like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *archivedObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"allowedStates"];
    OrderedDictionary *countryStates = (OrderedDictionary *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedObject];
```

I see that `archivedObject` is not empty, however `countryStates` is empty, although when I save it it's not empty.

How is it?

How can I archive successfully the `OrderedDictionary`?

**EDITED**

The method initWithCoder is being called, but not encodeWithCoder

Comment: What's `countryStates`? You mean `allowedStates`?

Comment: countryStates is OrderedDictionary object (actually the allowedStates that was saved in the NSUsersDefaults

Comment: Try this: `id countryStates = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedObject];` and see if `countryStates` has any value and its type.

Comment: @EliGanem it's 0x0a44dbf0 with 0 pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below link, may be will you get proper solution.

[encodeWithCoder is not called in derived class of the NSMutableDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004783/encodewithcoder-is-not-called-in-derived-class-of-the-nsmutabledictionary)

[When does encodeWithCoder get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741893/when-does-encodewithcoder-get-called)

Good Luck !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your class conforms to the `<NSCoding>` protocoll (so your class definition reads `@interface OrderedDictionary <NSCoding>`)

Else, the framework doesn't know it should call `encodeWithCoder:`

Comment: How can I make sure that it conforms to NSCoding?

Comment: I added <NSCoding> so it looks like this @interface OrderedDictionary : NSMutableDictionary<NSCoding> but still it doesn't help..