# Resume NSProgressIndicator animation after window minimised and then restored

Tags: cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I'm having trouble with the animation of some subclassed indeterminate `NSProgressIndicator`s. They start and stop animating without any issues. However, if I minimise the window while animating, `stopAnimation:` / `StopAnimation(NSObject sender)` is called, which makes sense to save resources if the window is not visible. I assume this is invoked from the cocoa framework itself looking at the stacktrace.

The problem then arises when the window is restored, the animation is not resumed.

I've seen you can use the [`NSCoding Protocol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/index.html) and can override `encodeWithEncoder:` / `EncodeTo(NSCoder encoder)` to save some state, and then use that saved state in `initWithCoder:` / `AppProgressIndicatorBar(NSCoder coder)` to resume. But the problem here was that my `encodeWithEncoder:` / `EncodeTo(NSCoder encoder)` was never called.

Looking at this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3741893/1229237) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3741925/1229237), it should be handled automatically if the object needs to be serialized. So I'm not sure why it's not being called.

That same answer says you can do it explicitly with `NSKeyedArchiver`, but then I would need to listen with [`NSWindowDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol) to know when the window is minimizing / restoring. In which case, I could just use this, and not use the NSCoding Protocol...

This just feels dirty, and I would imagine this is a very common scenario. So how should / do you resume animation? I'm new to cocoa, coming from a mostly .NET background, and I think this problem is a symptom of my limited cocoa knowledge.

I'm using Xamarin Mac, and have tried to give the Objective-C and C# method signatures. I'll be happy for a solution in either, I'll be able to (hopefully!) convert it to the C# equivalent.

For completeness, here is my current Xamarin Mac subclass using the NSCoder Protocol where `EncodeTo` is not being called. I'm running OS X 10.11.3 and Xamarin Studio 5.10.2.

```
[Register("AppProgressIndicatorBar")]
public class AppProgressIndicatorBar : NSProgressIndicator, INSCoding
{

   ...

    public AppProgressIndicatorBar(NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...

    public override void EncodeTo(NSCoder encoder)
    {
        base.EncodeTo(encoder);

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `NSWindowWillMiniaturizeNotification`, `NSWindowDidMiniaturizeNotification` and `NSWindowDidDeminiaturizeNotification` notifications or the `windowWillMiniaturize:`, `windowDidMiniaturize:` and `windowDidDeminiaturize:` Window delegate methods to track the state of your window and restore the state of your progress bar when the window deminiaturises (is that really a word?).

HTH